# Mean and Standard Deviation R=V/I

Tags: statistics

If voltage $v$ is fixed, but $I$  is random then R=$v/I$ is also random. 
If mean $I$ is 20 and standard deviation for $I$=.5

find approximations for mean $R$ and standard deviation of $R$?

Answer (score 0):

The usual model used in elementary physics courses suggests that if $I$ has mean $\mu_I$ and standard deviation $\sigma_I \ll |\mu_I|$, then we can approximate the mean of $R=f(I)$ by $f(\mu_I)$ and the standard deviation of $R$ by $\left |\frac{df}{dI}(\mu_I) \right | \sigma_I$.

Though this almost certainly answers your question, I will warn you that this model has issues under certain circumstances (for instance if $I$ is highly skewed).

Comment: Don't we also, strictly speaking, need some restrictions on growth of $f$ i.e. $((\log f')'(\mu_I)\sigma_I)^2$ has to be small as well?

Comment: @A.S. There are a lot of issues with this model, it's not easy to make a comprehensive list. The most basic one, to me, is that they more or less assume normality, but it is easy to have a non-integrable singularity if you assume normality (indeed it happens in this case). So somehow they have to assume some sort of "local normality", and it's never entirely clear to me what exactly they mean by that.

Comment: What you listed (mean and std) is true for any linear $f$ ($f''=0$) without any assumptions of "local normality". For it to hold in general, we need small $\frac {f''\sigma_I}{f'}$ (and small higher derivatives as well, but I think practically the 2nd matters most) and small $n\ge 3$ cumulants of $I$ relative to $\sigma_I^n$ (which would be zero in normal case). Again, in practice the third cumulant (skew) matters the most. This is basically the difference between first order and second order Taylor expansion of $f$ that specifies when one is not far from another.

Comment: Correction: it should be central moments, not cumulants above (which are the same for $n=3$).

Comment: @A.S. Sure in the linear case everything is fine. In the nonlinear case you need to either have a "nice" $f$ or else you need to assume that the distribution of $I$ remains away from regions where $f$ is bad. In the case of division, you are stuck with the latter: for instance, if $N$ is normally distributed with nonzero variance then $1/N$ doesn't have a well-defined mean.

Comment: @A.S. But nonetheless, the derivations of these kinds of results, at least those that I have seen, are based on an actual Taylor expansion of the characteristic function (or something similar), and the truncation at second order yields an actual normal variable (not a truncated normal variable or anything like that).

Comment: That explains the references to "local normality" (small higher central moments is basically a way to state that, I think). I thought of this as simply Taylor expanding $f$ around $\mu_I$ (to the second order) to find the first two moments of $f(I)$ and that's how I got $f''/f'$ condition. That matters because even if $f$ is "nice", but it peaks (or almost peaks) at $\sigma_I$ with large $f''$, approximation will suffer even w/out any singularities

Comment: @A.S. Ah, now I agree, when it comes to accuracy (rather than merely concern about completely nonsensical results), local derivative bounds do come into play.

Comment: Well, in a physical context, negative R don't makes sense either. For what its worth, for $f(x)=x^i$ for $|i|\in [1,3]$ (with $i=0$ standing for $\log$) or $f(x)=e^{x/s}$ ("typical" relations between physical quantities), small $(\frac {f''}{2f'}\sigma_I)^2$ translates into either small $(\frac {\sigma_I}{\mu_I})^2$ (slightly weaker than $\sigma_I\ll \mu_I$ you listed) or small $(\frac{\sigma_I}{c})^2$  - which is qualitatively different, since instead of $\mu_I$ it uses a more relevant characteristic scale of $I$ ($c$) and is independent of $\mu_I$.